# Two Action Sheets in one view

Tags: ios, ios4, uiactionsheet

I want to have two Action Sheets, but how can I know for which of them is called method `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would set the tag of those action sheets and checks the tag in the clickedButtonAtIndex.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your action sheet, store a reference and then check in the delegate method.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   if (actionSheet == actionSheet1) {
      // do something
   }
   else if (actionSheet == actionSheet2) {
      // do something else
   {
}
```

Comment: Note, actionSheet1 and actionSheet2 are member variables defined on the class, such that they can be later accessed in the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Careful this will not work when cancel is tapped in each of the action sheets You need to clear actionsheet1 if cancel is selected in the first actionsheet and actionsheet2 if cancel is selected in second actionsheet.